# External Blu-ray DVD drive causes internet connectivity issues

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, blu-ray

I am using a external Blu-ray DVD drive through a USB3.0-to-eSATA adapter. But whenever I connect the Blu-ray, I cannot connect to the internet thru wifi. If I remove it, I get wifi internet connectivity back immediately. How come this is happening? I thought the drivers are separated and they should not affect each other. I am using Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: This by chance a laptop?

Comment: Yes, it's VAIO Pro 13.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing the external drive and then rewiring all the cables of the drive. It's now working. Don't know why though.